# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reinstallation failure

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I'm new to Ubuntu and I my biggest crash so far.

I've been using 18.04 LTS without a hassle until I decided to update to 20.04 LTS. After the upgrade, and a couple of days of use, I found this image:

```
Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator.
```

So after this message, as I couldn't find a solution I moved to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 using a bootable USB. However, after selecting the USB at the UEFI terminal, I find this image once I select the “installing” option.

[image]

My current computer is a `Legion Y540 i7 8GB (BIOS Version BHCN28WW) (Secure Boot Disable)`

Thanks in advance!